# Magento 2 update & data migration from 1.9 - can't edit category

Tags: migration, magento-1.9, database-migration, magento2

I have a Magento 1.9.2.0 that's filled with categories, users, sales, products, etc. I also have a Magento 2.1.3 that is a fresh install. I've used the Data Migration Tool from Magento to import every content of the old version into the new.

First, I've updated Magento 2.1.3 -> 2.1.9. All good so far.
Then, I installed Data Import Tools, configured the connection, ran the migration and it successfully imported everything from 1.9.2.0 to the new 2.1.9. All good so far.

What happens next is whenever I create a category, it creates without a name. I can't change its name nor Anchor, but I can change its position and add/remove products to it. Going on the admin panel to make these changes, it says it was updated successfully, but it wasnt. I've ruled out cache issue and what it appears to be (as I was playing around with catalog_category_entity_varchar) is that somehow, whenever I create a category, it doesn't insert into this table their attributes and values.

All other tables, like sales, customer, products, are working as expected.

Any ideas or solutions?
I've gone to the length of trying chmod 777 to every single file (just in case it was a permission issue) without success.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-internal-spec.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not use data migration tool, as it gave errors after errors. What I ended up doing was a script to import what I considered - the most important data. That is, categories, clients, orders, products, images. Took a couple to find the equivalent id's and tables, below is the database schema that helped me.

http://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png

http://anna.voelkl.at/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ce2.1.3.png